# Не работает сравнение объектов по полям C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ObjectEqualsTest
{
    public class Point
    {
        public Int32 x, y;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj.GetType()!= this.GetType())
                return false;

            FieldInfo[] thisFieldsInfo = this.GetType().GetFields();

            FieldInfo[] objFieldsInfo = obj.GetType().GetFields();

            if (thisFieldsInfo.Length != objFieldsInfo.Length)
                return false;
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < thisFieldsInfo.Length; i++)
                {
                    if ((thisFieldsInfo[i].GetType() != objFieldsInfo[i].GetType()) &&
                      (thisFieldsInfo[i].Name != objFieldsInfo[i].Name)&& 
                        (thisFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(this) != objFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(obj)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(thisFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(this) + " " + objFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(obj));
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(thisFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(this) + " " + objFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(obj));
                        if (i == thisFieldsInfo.Length - 1)
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = 1502939027;
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + x.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + y.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point x1 = new Point(1, 3);
            Point x2 = new Point(1, 2);

            Console.WriteLine(x1.Equals(x2));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть вот такой код для сравнения двух объектов. Проблема в том, что if() с проверками на тип, имя и значение полей работает как-то неадекватно. Если закомментировать  первые две проверки - всегда выдаёт false, если разкомментирую первую и вторую проверки - всегда будет true, но ведь проверка значения выдаёт false, wtf. Не могу понять, что я не так делаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, Вы хотели поставить не `И`, a `ИЛИ`:

```
if ((thisFieldsInfo[i].GetType() != objFieldsInfo[i].GetType()) ||
    (thisFieldsInfo[i].Name != objFieldsInfo[i].Name) || 
    (thisFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(this) != objFieldsInfo[i].GetValue(obj)))
```

Во-вторых, `thisFieldsInfo[i].GetType()` и `objFieldsInfo[i].GetType()` возвращают тип `FieldInfo` - эта проверка бессмысленна.

В-третьих, `.GetValue` возвращает `object`, в который завернуто целое значение. Сравнение двух объектов происходит по их ссылкам - для разных объектов ссылки всегда разные.

---

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (!(obj is Point))
    return false;

  Point p = (Point)obj;
  return p.x == x && p.y == y;
}
```

---

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
    return false;

  FieldInfo[] fields = this.GetType().GetFields();
  for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
  {
    // need to check reference fields for null
    if (!fields[i].GetValue(this).Equals(fields[i].GetValue(obj)))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Припустим у меня есть тонна полей, 40+ например. Мне каждое из них придется прописывать используя &&?

Comment: Хотелось бы как-то рефлексию использовать, сделать "универсальный" метод сравнения объектов.

Comment: @AshenOne Как Вы думаете, почему .NET не содержит такого метода?

Comment: Потому что его нельзя запилить из-за ограничений компилятора/среды выполнения? Жизнь боль

Comment: @Igor, но ведь для анонимных классов содержит.

Comment: @AshenOne Если вы хотите создать класс с 40+ полей, то значит что-то в вашем решении не так. А так полно способов избежать этого. Разбейте поля на группы, каждый из которых засуньте в отдельную структуру. У структур сравнение через Equal происходит по полям автоматом. Или используйте словари, чтобы хранить однотипные данные. Наследованием воспользуйтесь, чтобы разделить эти 40+ полей по отдельным классам, где проверка будет занимать меньше места. Вообще для хранения данных и придумали структуры, а классы нужны, чтобы структурами управлять своей собственной логикой.

Comment: @AshenOne, сделайте сравнение по хэшкоду

Comment: @Александр: И что это даст?

Comment: @John, не всегда 40 полей - это плохо.