# Как инициализировать поля базового класса просто передав ему объект его же типа?

Tags: c#, ооп

Столкнулся с проблемой:
Мне надо проинициализировать базовый класс с минимальным написанием кода, потому что он может в будущем расшириться или измениться и не хотелось бы каждый раз лезть в конструктор и менять/добавлять присвоения полей.

Думаю код лучше выразит мою мысль) мне надо что бы было так:

```
class Base
{

    public Base(Base b)
    {
        this = b; // <--- Так не работет а очень хотелось бы
    }

    public int field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }

}

class Child: Base
{
    /// Конструктор потомка
    public Child(Base b, int field3) 
        : base(b)
    {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    public int field3 { get; set; }

}
```

Обязательно руками присваивать значения для `field1` и `field2`?
типо того:

```
/// Конструктор потомка
public Child(Base b, int field3) 
{
    this.field1 = b.field1;
    this.field2 = b.field2;
    this.field3 = field3;
}
```

Есть-ли не многословный и эффективный способ решения данной задачи?

Можно конечно применить автомаппер, но может есть способ решить эту задачу в c# стиле без наворотов и рефлексий?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934592/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-c/934593#934593

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/332516/

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас вопрос на тему паттерна [Prototype](https://youtu.be/Dk_ZqdLgLzY).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по вопросу:

> Как инициализировать поля базового класса просто передав ему объект его же типа?

Сама задача сводится к созданию полной копии обьекта в новый инстанс. Для этого не обязательно переинициализировать каждый проперти нового обьекта. Достаточно скопировать полностью старый обьект в новую область памяти.

Это можно сделать через ICloneable:

```
class myClass : ICloneable
{
    public String test;
    public myClass Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

и в таком случае ты просто берешь и делаешь:

```
var newInstance = oldInstance.Clone();
```

---

Это можно сделать через бинарную сериализацию и моментальную разсериализацию:

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
   var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
   ms.Position = 0;

   return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
 }
}
```

использование:

```
var newInstance = DeepClone<myClass>(myClassOldInstance);
```

можешь любой из этих кодов переделать под себя лично как твоей душе угодно